# How to hide the opaque gray information on MPC HC in the upper left of the video

Tags: codec, media-player-classic, ffdshow

I just updated K-Lite Codec Pack. The updated version of MPC HC is showing this gray opaque OSD box:

[image]
Anyone knows how to disable that? I can't seem to find the option to remove it. It's getting annoying when I'm trying to work with the video timings since I'm using the ffdshow current frame OSD and it's blocking the view when I do anything for a few secs.

A few secs numerous times breaks my workflow. Don't tell me to relocate the OSD information instead since I also want that gray opaque information removed when playing/watching videos normally, I get the status bar for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable **Show OSD** under `Options > Player > Other`:

[image: 1]